# c# search over multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I got a searchstring from the searchfield in the Frontend. I search in the View for it's matches. So far it works extremly fine. Now is the time to have a combined search for multiple fields like `firstname`, `lastname`, `City`, `Zip` and `Street`, but the order is not allways the same.
So how can I search in the view on multiple columns when the order is not allways the same?

My current codesnipped looks like this

```
public object SearchCustomer(SearchString st)
{

    DateTime dayOfBirth;
    DateTime.TryParse(st.Content, out dayOfBirth);

    var filteredQuery = 
        from pr in ctx.AllCustomerProcesses
        where
        pr.BirthDate1 == dayOfBirth
            || pr.BirthDate2 == dayOfBirth
            || pr.FirstName1.Contains(st.Content)
            || pr.LastName1.Contains(st.Content)
            || pr.FirstName2.Contains(st.Content)
            || pr.LastName2.Contains(st.Content)
            || pr.ProcessStatusDescription.Contains(st.Content)
            || (pr.LastName1  + " " + pr.FirstName1).Contains(st.Content)
            || (pr.FirstName1 + " " + pr.LastName1).Contains(st.Content)
            || (pr.LastName2  + " " + pr.FirstName2).Contains(st.Content)
            || (pr.FirstName2 + " " + pr.LastName2).Contains(st.Content)
        orderby pr.CustomerID descending
        select pr;
}
```

What is the best and performance optimized way to search for does 5 attributes?
(`FirstName1`, `LastName1`, `Street`, `Zip`, `City`). The result must match even if the order is not allways the same or some attributes are not given.

Comment: Does it `(pr.LastName1  + " " + pr.FirstName1).Contains(st.Content)` makes sense at all? Is there a lot of request to look for "onald Trum"?

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer from @MBurnham? If not, leave a comment and i´ll post an answer with Linq :) And if not: Do you need the object, which matches on you criteria as a return type or do you only want to know if the criteria matches?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server, it will be much better at searching than LINQ.

Create a table in your database that has 4 columns: A primary key, a varchar value, a column ID, and a reference (possibly a Foriegn Key) to the primary key in your `pr` table.

Then create a nonclustered index on the value column.

You will then use this table to store all of the attribute info for each person in one column. (The second column specified above).

That way you can utalize an index for all of the attributes at once.

You should add triggers to your `pr` table. That way, when a record is inserted, updated, or deleted in your `pr` table, you will automatically insert, update, or delete rows in your search table as well.

General Idea:

```
CREATE TABLE SearchTable (
    SearchID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , SearchValue VARCHAR(MAX)
    , MatchingColumnID INT
    , PrRecordID INT
);

-- create nonclustered index

-- create triggers

CREATE PROCEDURE SearchRecords
    @searchParam VARCHAR(50)
AS
    DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(52) = CONCAT('%', @searchParam, '%');

    SELECT DISTINCT st.PrRecordID
    FROM SearchTable AS st
    WHERE st.SearchValue LIKE @searchString;

END
```